# Django Filter Queryset by Highest Rating

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I have a model that allows for ratings of its objects, and I want to be able to filter by the highest rating, which is a number range that can be either a positive or negative integer:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = VotingField(can_change_vote=True)
    ....
```

The `VotingField` is from [a fork of django-ratings](https://github.com/Kronuz/django-ratings/blob/master/djangoratings/fields.py).

How do I filter this queryset to `order_by` the highest number `rating` out of all `Thing` objects? Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure whether you want highest average or highest sum so you may need to change the annotate

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Avg

Thing.objects.annotate(avg_rating=Avg('rating__score')).order_by('-avg_rating')
Thing.objects.annotate(sum_rating=Sum('rating__score')).order_by('-sum_rating')
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

It looks like you are calling your VotingField `rating` which looks like its essentially a has many to the `Vote` model. So we want the Sum or Avg of each `Thing`'s `Vote` collection's `score` field. (I think its the score field we want to annotate https://github.com/Kronuz/django-ratings/blob/master/djangoratings/models.py#L15 but I don't use this plugin so do a little research if this isn't what you need)

Comment: Thanks! That is very informative! For some reason, `rating_score` worked rather than `rating__score`, so in the end I used: `Thing.objects.annotate(sum_rating=Sum('rating_score')).order_by('-sum_rating')`. Thank you for your input. It solved my problem!

Comment: I am trying this solution and it seems to work ok. That's the second time I use django-ratings and I tried to achieve this with what is explained in the docs but in the end, like the first time, I end up using annotations. what @Nick B says about rating_score is also true for me, if not I get a FiledError and I am reminded by Django that I need to chose between rating_score and rating_votes.